# SQL Server Partitioning and FileGroups

Tags: sql-server-2008, partitioning

I have a single very large table (100s of millions of rows) that I want to partition. Is it standard (or good) practice to have the files and file groups laid in in a one to one fashion  (e.g. FG_2012 would contain only FILE_2012, FG_2011 would only containe FILE_2011, etc.). Most of the examples on the web show it this way but I'm not sure that that isn't for simplicity of explantion more than for good advice.

Comment: The more I think about this, the more I think this is a dumb question. I only have one table to partition and you can only partition by filegroup so I don't see that there is going to be much of a choice but for it to be one to one. With that said I can see that there could be a performance boost to have mutliple files per filegroup.

Comment: Do you have a reason to partition? What is it?

Comment: Performance benefits in terms of querying, faster backups (e.g. only needing to repetitively backup recently changed filegroups), and index maintenance etc. We will likely put the old data on separate slower spindle sets while putting the newest most needed data on SSDs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You answer in the comments that you intend to put old partitions onto cheap storage and change its backup scheme. Those are very good reasons for partitioning.

Those reasons force you to use multiple file groups. You are not forced to have one file group per partition, so you could partition by day and use file groups per year. That can be a good idea if you want to have many partitions (like 15.000 which is the maximum). In that case you don't want that many files on disk and it makes sense to not synchronize partitions with file groups.

I think it makes sense to have the two concepts aligned because it simplifies management, though. In your case (storage considerations) I'd go with aligned partitions and file groups. Maybe one of each per month or so.